# Pass list from Main Activity to tabs Fragment RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have activity which have 4 tabs and each tab has `RecyclerView`. I fetch Json data in `MainActivity` and then convert it into a List.

The challenge here is to pass the list to each `RecyclerView` in each `Fragment` in each tab.

Comment: could you show us some of your code, specially the main activity and the fragmens instantiation?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way would be using [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel.html) like this:

ViewModel:

```
public class SharedViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private List<Item> list_1= ArrayList<Item>();
    private List<Item> list_2= ArrayList<Item>();

    public void setList_1(List<Item> list) {
        list_1 = list
    }

    public List<Item> getList_1() {
        return list_1 ;
    }

    public void setList_2(List<Item> list) {
        list_2 = list
    }

    public List<Item> getList_2() {
        return list_2 ;
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SharedViewModel model;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_acticity);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        // Getting your lists here
        model.setList_1(list_1);
        model.setList_2(list_2);

    }
}
```

Fragment_1:

```
public class Fragment_1 extends Fragment {

    private SharedViewModel model;
    List<Item> list_1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        list_1 = model.getList_1();
    }
}
```

Fragment_2:

```
public class Fragment_2 extends Fragment {

    private SharedViewModel model;
    List<Item> list_2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        model = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
        list_2 = model.getList_2();
    }
}
```

But, better way is more complex.  More info here [Guide to App Architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html)

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a `BoradcastReceiver` in your `Fragment`. So when the lists for the fragments are updated, you send a broadcast from your `MainActivity` and the broadcast will be received in the Fragments.

You just have to register `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Fragment` like this.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Get extra data included in the Intent
        // You might consider sending a list to be passed to the adapter of the RecyclerView. 
        String data = intent.getStringExtra("data");
        // Update your RecyclerView with data. 
    }
};
```

Register the receiver in the `Fragment` inside your `onResume` function.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // Register to receive messages.
    // We are registering an observer (mMessageReceiver) to receive Intents
    // with actions named "update-frag-1-recyclerview".
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("update-frag-1-recyclerview"));
    super.onResume();
}
```

And un-register the receiver in `onPause` function in your `Fragment`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Unregister since the Fragment is paused.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(
            mMessageReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Now from your `Activity` when the data is received and you are now ready to pass the data to your fragments, just send the broadcasts accordingly to be received by your fragments. I am showing one.

```
Intent intent = new Intent("update-frag-1-recyclerview");
// You can also include some extra data.
intent.putExtra("data", "This is some data!");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

This will trigger the `onReceive` function in your `Fragment1` as you are listening to the event which is `update-frag-1-recyclerview` from `Fragment1`. You can do the same thing for other fragments as well. Keep in mind that I am only sending just one data which is `String`. You might consider sending a list as well as an extra along with the intent to be received in the `Fragment`.

Hope that helps!